# What does 'MyApps application' mean? --- Android in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want the implement the in-app billing feature in android platform. When I learn the docs of Google SDK. I found the following text, But I don't understand the meaning of 'MyApps application'. Does it mean other android appstores?

*If your device is running Android 3.0, in-app billing requires version 5.0.12 (or higher) of the **MyApps application**. If your device is running any other version of Android, in-app billing requires version 2.3.4 (or higher) of the Google Play application.*

Comment: As you may notice this app is only applicable for Android-powered devices running specific Android version 3.0. For the rest devices you should have Google Play app. So if your app is targeting Android 3.1+ then no worries.